# Postgres import issues - huge table shows 0 rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, postgresql-11

I have an issue with a database import. Basically, I am doing this on a postgres 9.6 (production):

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump  mydb | /bin/gzip | /usr/bin/ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cat > /root/20210130.sql.gz"
```

And on a remote machine I am importing on Postgres 11 like this:

```
step 1: import schema from a beta machine with Postgres 11
step 2: import data from that export like this: time zcat 20210130.sql.gz | psql mydb
```

The issue that I have is that one of the tables has 0 rows even though it uses a lot of disk space.

In the original db:

```
    table_schema    |        table_name        | row_estimate |   total    |   index    |   toast    |   table    
--------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 public             | test                     |   5.2443e+06 | 18 GB      | 13 GB      | 8192 bytes | 4864 MB
```

In the new db:

```
    table_schema    |        table_name        | row_estimate |   total    |   index    |   toast    |   table
--------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 public             | test                     |            0 | 4574 MB    | 4574 MB    | 8192 bytes | 16 kB
```

What is going on here? How can I fix it?

I can't import the entire DB again because it needed ~7 hours to do the import.

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: I got some like these:
ERROR:  insert or update on table "test_ndt" violates foreign key constraint "test_ndt_test_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (test_id)=(10022566) is not present in table "test"

Comment: So you need to fix the problem and repeat.  Yes, it will take a long time.

Comment: With the options you (didn't) give to pg_dump, it will export the schema along with the  data.  So your step 1 doesn't make any sense.  Why did you do that?  Is it an attempt to work around the problem that you are dumping with an old version of pg_dump but targeting a newer version of Postgresql?